# Any reason one Linux server affect speed of another Linux server

Tags: linux, performance, matlab

I have two Linux server, and MATLAB is installed independently on each server.
One day, we have found that running many MALTAB jobs using SLURM on one machine(1) somehow slows down MATLAB on the other machine(2).

First, I thought it might be caused by SLURM, so I turned off SLURM on second machine. However, it did not help. I have checked CPU usage, but CPU usage for second machine has not changed while first machine is running. The two servers don't share memory or CPU. They do have some shared mounted directories, but I'm not sure if it can reduce speed of MATLAB this much.

Would there be any idea about what is going on and how I can examine this?
Thank you.

Added: There are a bit of updates. I have checked bench for MATLAB of second machine again with even more jobs running on first machine. The 2-D and 3-D worktime greatly increased on second machine. I hope this helps to find out the reason.

[Default](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YKt4e.jpg)

[After many MATLAB jobs are running on first machine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WfzYH.jpg)

Comment: How did you determine the speed of MATLAB? What process is running in MATLAB on the two machines? Is the MATLAB directory shared? Are the processes writing to the same networked partition? There are so many thing to look at…

Comment: Thx for the comment! I'm not an expert here, so I'm sorry that I did not include enough info. When examining speed of MATLAB, MATLAB benchmark results on second machine are not significantly different. However, if I run any jobs manually, it definitely takes longer to start, run, and finish even for the simple task such as "cd". The MATLAB is installed in local directory, so the MATLAB directory is not shared. For the network partition, I'm not sure what you meant by this, is there any ways to figure out?

Comment: Something must be shared.  Are they real systems or VM?  Are the matlab instances somehow linked?  Ex. a license server, shared drive, NFS, ...